# Facebook client-side OAuth 2.0 questions

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook, oauth-2.0

The context is a desktop app using the client-side OAuth flow for authentication.

When I first built this app nearly a year ago, Facebook's documentation said to use the following URL to generate the login/authorization dialog:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYYYY
```

This is working right now.  However, I've reviewed the newly updated Authentication Guide and now see that Facebook is saying to use:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYYYY
```

Does anyone know what the difference is between them, and more importantly do I need to change it?  Like I said, it is working now, but I'm a little concerned about something changing when the 10/01/2011 deadline comes around.

My second question is: Does anyone know what enabling the "OAuth Migration" setting in the Apps -> *AppName* -> Advanced page does?

Answer (score 2):

The URLs redirect to each other. But still, please make the change to the new URL. Whenever the docs change urls and the semantics are the same, you should update so as to avoid unnecessary breaking changes. Even more so with desktop apps.

Second answer: That will issue you different access tokens for now.

Comment: It's better for your users too if you switch to the new one since it'll skip an unnecessary hop.

Comment: @uɐɾɹɐʇ ןnɐd. Thank you, I will change to the new URL.  When you say "That will issue you different access tokens for now.", what does that really mean in terms of my app and users?  Can both kinds of access tokens be used interchangeably with the Graph API right now?

Comment: @daaku - Can you shed light on "unnecessary hop"? From my testing, both URLs redirect to the same location, `https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?<params>`.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right. I thought it's wasn't supposed to do that, I'll follow up.